# append 0 infront of single digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i'm trying to add a 0 infront of days / months with single digits. I tried using regular expressions but it doesn't seem to work. is there something i'm missing?

```
var newDate = new Date();
            alert(newDate);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            alert(newDate);
            var year = newDate.getFullYear();
            alert(year);
            var month = (newDate.getMonth()+1).replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1');
            alert(month);
            var day = newDate.getDate().replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1');
alert(day);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd better use these constructions.

```
var month = (newDate.getMonth()+1).toString();
    month = month.length < 2 ? '0' + month : month;
alert(month);

var day = (newDate.getDate()+1).toString();
    day = day.length < 2 ? '0' + day : day;
alert(day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running `replace` on a Number here.

```
var month = (newDate.getMonth()+1).replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1');
// ...
var day = newDate.getDate().replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1');
```

You need to convert it to a String before running replace.

```
var month = (newDate.getMonth()+1).toString().replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1');
var day = newDate.getDate().toString().replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var month = "" + (newDate.getMonth()+1);
if (month.length==1) month = "0" + month;
alert(month);
var day = "" + newDate.getDate();
if (day.length == 1) day = "0" + day;
alert(day);
```